# Настройка Jenkins + Gerrit

Tags: git, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Задача: настроить окружение, в котором будет выполнятся построение проекта после отправки кода на ревью в gerrit.

Для интеграции с gerrit'ом использовал этот мануал: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Gerrit-jenkins-hudson (по нему нужно поставить и настроить плагин Gerrit Trigger).

Застрял на пункте "Integration with Gerrit", "Advanced (above repository browser) Choosing strategy".
Выбор стратегии у меня отсутствует

[image: SCM settings]

версия Gerrit Trigger - v2.17.2
версия Jenkins - 1.635

Я полагаю, что необходимая настройка была куда то перенесена в новых версиях. В мануале к плагину есть картинка с ней: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

Как обойти проблему? Есть ли другие пути привязки gerrit'а к jenkins'у?